# MPD ERROR: Failed to open audio output after re-installing

Tags: sound, mpd

Having MPD v.0.19 and Ubuntu 15.04 for quite some time now I wanted to check out the latest version 0.20 thus downloaded it and followed the instructions to compile it on my own.

Unfortunately this did not work out so I want to fall back to the official .deb MPD v0.19.

Now after re-installing mpd by `sudo apt-get purge mpd && sudo apt-get install mpd` the following pops up when I try to play a song:

`cat /var/log/mpd/mpd.log`:

```
Nov 05 14:22 : client: [13] opened from local
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4260:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4260:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4260:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4739:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Nov 05 14:22 : alsa_output: Failed to open "My ALSA Device" [alsa]: Failed to open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory
Nov 05 14:22 : output: Failed to open audio output
Nov 05 14:22 : client: [13] closed
```

`mpd -v`:

```
config_file: loading file /etc/mpd.conf
errno: Failed to open /etc/mpd.conf: Permission denied
```

`ls -la /etc/mpd.conf`:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mpd audio 14092 Jun 23 00:05 /etc/mpd.conf
```

`mpd.conf`:

```
# An example configuration file for MPD.
# Read the user manual for documentation: http://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/
# or /usr/share/doc/mpd/user-manual.html


# Files and directories #######################################################
#
# This setting controls the top directory which MPD will search to discover the
# available audio files and add them to the daemon's online database. This 
# setting defaults to the XDG directory, otherwise the music directory will be
# be disabled and audio files will only be accepted over ipc socket (using
# file:// protocol) or streaming files over an accepted protocol.
#
music_directory     "/var/lib/mpd/music"
#
# This setting sets the MPD internal playlist directory. The purpose of this
# directory is storage for playlists created by MPD. The server will use 
# playlist files not created by the server but only if they are in the MPD
# format. This setting defaults to playlist saving being disabled.
#
playlist_directory      "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"
#
# This setting sets the location of the MPD database. This file is used to
# load the database at server start up and store the database while the 
# server is not up. This setting defaults to disabled which will allow
# MPD to accept files over ipc socket (using file:// protocol) or streaming
# files over an accepted protocol.
#
db_file         "/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache"
# 
# These settings are the locations for the daemon log files for the daemon.
# These logs are great for troubleshooting, depending on your log_level
# settings.
#
# The special value "syslog" makes MPD use the local syslog daemon. This
# setting defaults to logging to syslog, otherwise logging is disabled.
#
log_file            "/var/log/mpd/mpd.log"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which stores the process ID
# for use of mpd --kill and some init scripts. This setting is disabled by
# default and the pid file will not be stored.
#
pid_file            "/run/mpd/pid"
#
# This setting sets the location of the file which contains information about
# most variables to get MPD back into the same general shape it was in before
# it was brought down. This setting is disabled by default and the server 
# state will be reset on server start up.
#
state_file          "/var/lib/mpd/state"
#
# The location of the sticker database.  This is a database which
# manages dynamic information attached to songs.
#
sticker_file                   "/var/lib/mpd/sticker.sql"
#
###############################################################################


# General music daemon options ################################################
#
# This setting specifies the user that MPD will run as. MPD should never run as
# root and you may use this setting to make MPD change its user ID after
# initialization. This setting is disabled by default and MPD is run as the
# current user.
#
user                "mpd"
#
# This setting specifies the group that MPD will run as. If not specified
# primary group of user specified with "user" setting will be used (if set).
# This is useful if MPD needs to be a member of group such as "audio" to
# have permission to use sound card.
#
#group                          "nogroup"
#
# This setting sets the address for the daemon to listen on. Careful attention
# should be paid if this is assigned to anything other then the default, any.
# This setting can deny access to control of the daemon. Choose any if you want
# to have mpd listen on every address. Not effective if systemd socket
# activation is in use.
#
# For network
bind_to_address     "localhost"
#
# And for Unix Socket
#bind_to_address        "/run/mpd/socket"
#
# This setting is the TCP port that is desired for the daemon to get assigned
# to.
#
#port               "6600"
#
# This setting controls the type of information which is logged. Available 
# setting arguments are "default", "secure" or "verbose". The "verbose" setting
# argument is recommended for troubleshooting, though can quickly stretch
# available resources on limited hardware storage.
#
#log_level          "default"
#
# If you have a problem with your MP3s ending abruptly it is recommended that 
# you set this argument to "no" to attempt to fix the problem. If this solves
# the problem, it is highly recommended to fix the MP3 files with vbrfix
# (available as vbrfix in the debian archive), at which
# point gapless MP3 playback can be enabled.
#
#gapless_mp3_playback           "yes"
#
# Setting "restore_paused" to "yes" puts MPD into pause mode instead
# of starting playback after startup.
#
#restore_paused "no"
#
# This setting enables MPD to create playlists in a format usable by other
# music players.
#
#save_absolute_paths_in_playlists   "no"
#
# This setting defines a list of tag types that will be extracted during the 
# audio file discovery process. The complete list of possible values can be
# found in the mpd.conf man page.
#metadata_to_use    "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date,composer,performer,disc"
#
# This setting enables automatic update of MPD's database when files in 
# music_directory are changed.
#
#auto_update    "yes"
#
# Limit the depth of the directories being watched, 0 means only watch
# the music directory itself.  There is no limit by default.
#
#auto_update_depth "3"
#
###############################################################################


# Symbolic link behavior ######################################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following 
# symbolic links outside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_outside_symlinks    "yes"
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following
# symbolic links inside of the configured music_directory.
#
#follow_inside_symlinks     "yes"
#
###############################################################################


# Zeroconf / Avahi Service Discovery ##########################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", service information will be published with
# Zeroconf / Avahi.
#
#zeroconf_enabled       "yes"
#
# The argument to this setting will be the Zeroconf / Avahi unique name for
# this MPD server on the network.
#
#zeroconf_name          "Music Player"
#
###############################################################################


# Permissions #################################################################
#
# If this setting is set, MPD will require password authorization. The password
# can setting can be specified multiple times for different password profiles.
#
#password                        "password@read,add,control,admin"
#
# This setting specifies the permissions a user has who has not yet logged in. 
#
#default_permissions             "read,add,control,admin"
#
###############################################################################


# Database #######################################################################
#

#database {
#       plugin "proxy"
#       host "other.mpd.host"
#       port "6600"
#}

# Input #######################################################################
#

input {
        plugin "curl"
#       proxy "proxy.isp.com:8080"
#       proxy_user "user"
#       proxy_password "password"
}

#
###############################################################################

# Audio Output ################################################################
#
# MPD supports various audio output types, as well as playing through multiple 
# audio outputs at the same time, through multiple audio_output settings 
# blocks. Setting this block is optional, though the server will only attempt
# autodetection for one sound card.
#
# An example of an ALSA output:
#
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
#   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
#   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "default"   # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#   mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
#
# An example of an OSS output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "oss"
#   name        "My OSS Device"
#   device      "/dev/dsp"  # optional
#   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "/dev/mixer"    # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#}
#
# An example of a shout output (for streaming to Icecast):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "shout"
#   encoding    "ogg"           # optional
#   name        "My Shout Stream"
#   host        "localhost"
#   port        "8000"
#   mount       "/mpd.ogg"
#   password    "hackme"
#   quality     "5.0"
#   bitrate     "128"
#   format      "44100:16:1"
#   protocol    "icecast2"      # optional
#   user        "source"        # optional
#   description "My Stream Description" # optional
#   url             "http://example.com"    # optional
#   genre       "jazz"          # optional
#   public      "no"            # optional
#   timeout     "2"         # optional
#   mixer_type      "software"              # optional
#}
#
# An example of a recorder output:
#
#audio_output {
#       type            "recorder"
#       name            "My recorder"
#       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame
#       path            "/var/lib/mpd/recorder/mpd.ogg"
##      quality         "5.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined
#       bitrate         "128"                   # do not define if quality is defined
#       format          "44100:16:1"
#}
#
# An example of a httpd output (built-in HTTP streaming server):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "httpd"
#   name        "My HTTP Stream"
#   encoder     "vorbis"        # optional, vorbis or lame
#   port        "8000"
#   bind_to_address "0.0.0.0"               # optional, IPv4 or IPv6
#   quality     "5.0"           # do not define if bitrate is defined
#   bitrate     "128"           # do not define if quality is defined
#   format      "44100:16:1"
#   max_clients     "0"                     # optional 0=no limit
#}
#
# An example of a pulseaudio output (streaming to a remote pulseaudio server)
# Please see README.Debian if you want mpd to play through the pulseaudio
# daemon started as part of your graphical desktop session!
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "pulse"
#   name        "My Pulse Output"
#   server      "remote_server"     # optional
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional
#}
#
# An example of a winmm output (Windows multimedia API).
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "winmm"
#   name        "My WinMM output"
#   device      "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)" # optional
#       or
#   device      "0"     # optional
#   mixer_type  "hardware"  # optional
#}
#
# An example of an openal output.
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "openal"
#   name        "My OpenAL output"
#   device      "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)" # optional
#}
#
## Example "pipe" output:
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "pipe"
#   name        "my pipe"
#   command     "aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or if you're want to use AudioCompress
#   command     "AudioCompress -m | aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null"
## Or to send raw PCM stream through PCM:
#   command     "nc example.org 8765"
#   format      "44100:16:2"
#}
#
## An example of a null output (for no audio output):
#
#audio_output {
#   type        "null"
#   name        "My Null Output"
#   mixer_type      "none"                  # optional
#}
#
# If MPD has been compiled with libsamplerate support, this setting specifies 
# the sample rate converter to use.  Possible values can be found in the 
# mpd.conf man page or the libsamplerate documentation. By default, this is
# setting is disabled.
#
#samplerate_converter       "Fastest Sinc Interpolator"
#
###############################################################################


# Normalization automatic volume adjustments ##################################
#
# This setting specifies the type of ReplayGain to use. This setting can have
# the argument "off", "album", "track" or "auto". "auto" is a special mode that
# chooses between "track" and "album" depending on the current state of
# random playback. If random playback is enabled then "track" mode is used.
# See <http://www.replaygain.org> for more details about ReplayGain.
# This setting is off by default.
#
#replaygain         "album"
#
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that have ReplayGain tags. By
# default this setting is disabled.
#
#replaygain_preamp      "0"
#
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that do NOT have ReplayGain tags.
# By default this setting is disabled.
#
#replaygain_missing_preamp  "0"
#
# This setting enables or disables ReplayGain limiting.
# MPD calculates actual amplification based on the ReplayGain tags
# and replaygain_preamp / replaygain_missing_preamp setting.
# If replaygain_limit is enabled MPD will never amplify audio signal
# above its original level. If replaygain_limit is disabled such amplification
# might occur. By default this setting is enabled.
#
#replaygain_limit       "yes"
#
# This setting enables on-the-fly normalization volume adjustment. This will
# result in the volume of all playing audio to be adjusted so the output has 
# equal "loudness". This setting is disabled by default.
#
#volume_normalization       "no"
#
###############################################################################


# Character Encoding ##########################################################
#
# If file or directory names do not display correctly for your locale then you 
# may need to modify this setting.
#
filesystem_charset      "UTF-8"
#
# This setting controls the encoding that ID3v1 tags should be converted from.
#
id3v1_encoding          "UTF-8"
#
###############################################################################


# SIDPlay decoder #############################################################
#
# songlength_database:
#  Location of your songlengths file, as distributed with the HVSC.
#  The sidplay plugin checks this for matching MD5 fingerprints.
#  See http://www.c64.org/HVSC/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.faq
#
# default_songlength:
#  This is the default playing time in seconds for songs not in the
#  songlength database, or in case you're not using a database.
#  A value of 0 means play indefinitely.
#
# filter:
#  Turns the SID filter emulation on or off.
#
#decoder {
#       plugin                  "sidplay"
#       songlength_database     "/media/C64Music/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.txt"
#       default_songlength      "120"
#       filter "true"
#}
#
###############################################################################
```

The sound of my system is working all fine, it's just MPD/MPC that can not play sound.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me ran `sudo adduser mpd` while trying to get the custom version from git working.
This was problematic with the actual MPD.

Solution:
`sudo deluser mpd`
In case it fails due to the MPD still running:

`ps aux | grep mpd`

and

`sudo kill -9 id-of-running-process`

Enjoy!